# Filter Implementation in Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have three collections,

**collection 1: subjects**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
   name: 'Subject Name',
   ...
}
```

**collection 2: filters**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
   filterName: 'Filter One',
   ...
}
```

**collection 3: subject_filters**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
   subjectId: {
      ref: 'subjects'
   },
   filterId: {
      ref: 'filters'
   },
   ...
}
```

Now I am creating a UI where user can view subjects by filters, where they can select multiple filters, If no filters were selected then **all subjects** will be returned, there's also a possiblity that **some subjects** are **not** present in **subject_filters** but they should appear in the UI, if no filters were selected. How to achive this. I have all the ids of filters seleced by user in an array **castedFilterIds** (can be empty), What I have tried is

```
db.subjects_filter.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {filterId: {$in: castedFilterIds}} // I managed to add this conditionally, if castedFilterIds length is > 0
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$subjectId',
      doc: {$first: '$$ROOT'},
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: '$doc',
    }
  },
])
```

This is returning only those subjects which are associcated with filters, but I need to query on all subjects. Any help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try condition this way `{ $match: castedFilterIds.length > 0 ? { filterId: { $in: castedFilterIds } } : {} }`

Comment: @turivishal Thanks, I did that already. My problem lies with returning all subjects if castedIds is empty, but in this case, only subjects associated with filter is getting returned, suppose i have a subject which is not in subject_filters.